# Text justifying problem when using monospaced font

Tags: fonts, horizontal-alignment

I got text justifying problem when I change the default font to a monospaced font, as you can see in my MWE.

Note that this does not only happen in `article` class, but also in `memoir`, `book`, as well.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tgcursor}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

How can I fix it? Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is, that monospaced fonts also have a fixed width space between words, so TeX cannot stretch these spaces. You have to adjust the interword space settings. The following solution is adapted from http://texblog.net/latex-archive/plaintex/full-justification-with-typewriter-font/

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{everysel}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\EverySelectfont{%
\fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
\fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
\fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
\fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
\hyphenchar\font=`\-% to allow hyphenation
}
\usepackage{tgcursor}

\begin{document}
\selectfont % Force initial font feature selection
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: justify]

Comment: Using the appropriate hyphenation patters for latin will improve the result too: `\usepackage[latin]{babel}`

Comment: Sure. One should always load babel with the right language. Although I don't think it is a good idea to add it to the MWE. That could be confusing for beginners who maybe think it is necessary for their document even though they most likely do not write in latin.

Comment: Agreed - I mentioned it because loading the correct hyphenation patterns improves the original layout quite a bit.